# mysql syntax error in a join query

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a mysql syntax error with the following query.

```
SELECT student_info.grade,
       student_info.section,
       student_info.student_name,
       mwf.*
FROM student_info
INNER JOIN mwf ON student_info.student_gen_id = mwf.mwf_student_id
WHERE mwf.mwf_month =".$current_month
```

error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 2014' at line 4

here `mwf_month` is string type the value I am passing as `current_month` is `october, 2014`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Complete model function generating the query

```
public function transaction_report_total($current_month) {
        $sql = "SELECT student_info.grade,
                student_info.section,
                student_info.student_name,
                mwf.*
                FROM student_info
                INNER JOIN mwf ON student_info.student_gen_id = mwf.mwf_student_id
                WHERE mwf.mwf_month = '" . $current_month."'";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: Put single quotes around your string variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the type of `mwf_month` is string, you need to add single quotes between `$current_month` as below

```
SELECT student_info.grade, student_info.section, student_info.student_name, mwf.* 
FROM student_info
INNER JOIN mwf ON student_info.student_gen_id = mwf.mwf_student_id
WHERE mwf.mwf_month = '".$current_month."'
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like the SQL statement ends after `$current_month`, so the double quote in the end is actually needed

```
$sql = "SELECT student_info.grade,
        student_info.section,
        student_info.student_name,
        mwf.*
        FROM student_info
        INNER JOIN mwf ON student_info.student_gen_id = mwf.mwf_student_id
        WHERE mwf.mwf_month = '".$current_month."'";
```

Comment: Thanks @MKhalidJunaid, I have removed the double quote.

Comment: it doesn't work without the removed doulbe quote

Comment: @Alvi_1987 can you edit the question and add more code that generates the query?

Comment: i am using codeigniter. putting this query in a varibale called $sql
and calling it using $this->db->query($sql)

Comment: @Alvi_1987 According to your question this answer is right if you have other problems then update your question accordingly also with proper error information

Comment: @Alvi_1987 please add the complete code statement that generates the `$sql` variable to your question, i.e `$sql = "SELECT student_info.grade, .....`

Comment: Does the updated code work? If not, what's the error you got?

Comment: Updated code works like your solution with an extra double quote, which was removed on @MKhalidJunaid's suggestion. So what's the confusion? So far I know Junaid provide authentic solutions.

Comment: I see, I think there was a misunderstanding because you didn't provide the complete code with the `$sql` variable, so it wasn't clear if the extra double quote is needed or not.